# Sql Query t find out maximum from name field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 5 tables with field name name . &  which name is appear maximum time in each table then I need to find out which output is maximum in all answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select top 1 name, count(*) from table
group by name
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the [other response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192467/sql-query-t-find-out-maximum-from-name-field/4192481#4192481), if there is more than one name with the top number of occurrences then something along these lines will work:

```
;WITH cte (Name, NoOccurrences) AS 
(
  SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) FROM [Table] GROUP BY Name
)
SELECT Name, NoOccurrences FROM cte 
WHERE NoOccurrences = (SELECT MAX(NoOccurrences) FROM cte)
```